# How to normalise a list of more than 25 Millions records using MinMaxScaler's fit_transform

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a list of more than 25 million records(1D Array). I want to normalise the values between 0 to 5.

I'm using scikit-learn's MinMaxScaler for this. This thing is working fine to records till 20M but as the size increasing it is taking huge of time.

Any suggestions how to do this in optimised way.

Comment: Did you check `partial_fit` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.partial_fit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale dataframes consistently MinMaxScaler() sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732108/how-to-scale-dataframes-consistently-minmaxscaler-sklearn)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732108/how-to-scale-dataframes-consistently-minmaxscaler-sklearn